# How do you read properties in a build defintion workflow (TFS 2010)

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, tfsbuild, build-definition

I have added a property to a TFS Build Workflow on the Arguments tab:

[image: Addition of Database Projects Property]

How do I reference this from an expression in my workflow? It did not come through as a public property to read and write as I expected.

If I set it with the Direction, 'In' I can read its value in an expression; it is resolved a friend variable in the workflow. Using the direction 'In' does not expose the property to be set when configuring a build, which I require.

Comment: Have you added it to the "Metadata" Argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any input that you have pass on to the build definition through UI must be added to the Metadata argument. Click on the MetaData argument and set the values. Then it will show up in the build defintion UI.